# How to use WebDav to match dav:href to Outolook Interop href value

Tags: .net, email, interop, outlook, webdav

I have previously used webdav to access the sent messages on an exchange 2003 server based on the subject and time and this has worked.

I now need to implement another feature which means dragging a message from client outlook (not web access) on to a windows form then querying webdav on exchange to get all the information about this message.

I can get the messages href using the following code:

```
Dim msg As MAPI.Message = CType(session.GetMessage(mail.EntryID), MAPI.Message)
Dim id as string = CType(CType(msg.Fields(), MAPI.Fields).Item(&H6707001E), MAPI.Field).Value.ToString
```

However there are two issues;

1) The encoding on the URL is different between what I get from the dragged message and what is brought back from webdav (I can see these if I ask for all mail).

2) No matter how I format the query it never brings back results even if I copy the href from the list when I bring back all messages.

Here is a sample of a search request that fails (works if you remove the where clause):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <D:searchrequest xmlns:D="DAV:">
        <D:sql>SELECT "DAV:contentclass","DAV:href", "DAV:displayname","urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived","urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" 
FROM "https://server/exchange/mailbox" WHERE "DAV:href"='/Inbox/email.EML'</D:sql>
    </D:searchrequest>
```

I have been using relative syntax as per [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295408) but have tried many combinations.

Comment: Dont u need a useralias in the url ?

Comment: I have tried with and with out (useralias being the mailbox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite long winded, but I have yet to find a better way of doing this:

The Outlook.MailItem.EntryID contains 4 Guids, although I am not sure what they all map to.  The last guid contains the information you are after.

00000000E6053DD369FAB340B6B8C4D77A0
B37D30700173A23D2AA06A3488E75E759DD
1ACBBB00000A6F78CC00007B9F3D877B316
4499DE695FBB7FCDE5F00000 **EBD83B9** 0000

The bold part is the Messages ID that we can use (Of all the messages in my inbox, only these 7 digits were different between their entry IDs).

Next, modify your webDAV query to bring back the `DAV:permanenturl` property.  This will look like the following:

https://SERVER_NAME/exchange/MAILBOX@DOMAIN>COM/-FlatUrlSpace-/173a23d2aa06a3488e75e759dd1acbbb-a6f78cc/7b9f3d877b3164499de695fbb7fcde5f-**ebd83b9**

So all you need to do for matching is to do a webDAV query for all the items in the specified mailbox, loop through comparing the **PermanentURL** with part of the **EntryID** to find your match.

I would be happier if there was an EntryID on the webDAV, but there does not seem to be a directly accessible one.

Answer (score 0):

When I wanted to figure out how to send WebDav to Exchange 2003, I fired up Fiddler2 and looked at the messages Outlook Web Access was sending.  You need Fiddler2 if you want to unpack the https responses.